# Automapper SetValue based on Property Name

Tags: c#, automapper

Trying to use AutoMapper to set property values based on Property Name ...

DTO ...

```
/// <summary>
/// DTO for the Performance Overview Report
/// </summary>
public class PerformanceOverviewDto
{
    public OverviewDto Summary1  { get; set; }
    public OverviewDto Summary2 { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// DTO for the WorkIn Overview 
/// </summary>
public class OverviewDto : MetricOverviewDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Total Hours for the Period
    /// </summary>
    public Decimal? TotalHours { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Average Hours per working day 
    /// </summary>
    public string AvgHoursPerWorkingDay { get; set; } 
}
```

Units is an extra property in my ViewModel for labelling

```
public class MetricsOverviewModel
{
    public MetricSummaryModel Summary1 { get; set; }
    public MetricSummaryModel Summary2 { get; set; }
}

public class MetricSummaryModel
{
    public string MinForPeriod { get; set; }
    public string MaxForPeriod { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalHours { get; set; }
    public string AvgHoursPerWorkingDay { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MetricSeriesOverviewDto> AllValuesPerTimePeriod { get; set; }
}
```

For "Summary2" .. I want to override the default value for Units ..

```
public class WebAutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<OverviewDto, MetricSummaryModel>()
            .ForMember(prop => prop.Units, opt => opt.UseValue(Strings.HoursinShort));
        CreateMap<PerformanceOverviewDto, MetricsOverviewModel>()
            .ForMember(prop => prop.Summary1.Units, opt => opt.UseValue(Strings.PercentSymbol));
    }
}
```

I am getting ...
Expression 'prop => prop.Summary1.Units' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.

Thanks in advance!
Keith.

Comment: Could you also include the code for OverviewDto and PerformanceOverviewDto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the code for your DTOs, but my guess would be that you want the following:

```
CreateMap<OverviewDto, MetricSummaryModel>()
    .ForMember(prop => prop.Units, opt => opt.UseValue(Strings.HoursinShort));
CreateMap<PerformanceOverviewDto, MetricsOverviewModel>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Summary1.Units = Strings.PercentSymbol);
```

Basically, if you are mapping from `PerformanceOverviewDto` --> `MetricsOverviewModelthis`, this uses the first `CreateMap` to map from `OverviewDto` to `MetricSummary`, but then it uses `AfterMap` to override `Strings.HoursinShort` with `Strings.PercentSymbol`.